# Koin: Why after myObject.scope.close(), it still works?

Tags: kotlin, service-locator, koin, koin-scope

I have a scope

```
scope<MyObject> {
    scoped { Presenter() }
}
```

Then when I get presenter, this works.

```
val presenter = myObject.scope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
```

Similarly, when I can assign a scope variable, then get the presenter.

```
val myScope = myObject.scope
val presenter = myScope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
```

If we close it, this is still okay

```
val presenter = myObject.scope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
myObject.scope.close()
val presenter2 = myObject.scope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
```

However if I assign to another scope variable, and close it, it will fail.

```
val myScope = myObject.scope
val presenter = myScope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
myScope.close()
val presenter2 = myScope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java) // Crash here.
```

Similarly, if I do this, it will crash too

```
val myScope = myObject.scope
val presenter = myScope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
myScope.close()
myScope.getOrCreateScope() // Crash here
val presenter2 = myScope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
```

I understand after `close()`, the scope can't get to provide the `presenter` anymore.
I just don't understand why after `myObject.scope.close()`, `myObject.scope` still can provide  presenter? (and the same presenter)

```
val presenter = myObject.scope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
myObject.scope.close()
val presenter2 = myObject.scope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java) 
// presenter1 == presenter2
```

Comment: Suspect Koin bug. Filed issue in https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/786

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `myObject.scope` is actually `myObject.getOrCreateScope()`. Hence even after `myObject.scope.close()` is called, `myObject.scope` will still work as it will create a new scope again.

But if we do the below (closing it), regardless of using `myScope` or `myObject.scope`, it will still close, and hence use it again from `myScope` will crash.

```
val myScope = myObject.scope
val presenter = myScope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
myObject.scope.close() // or myScope.scope
val presenter2 = myScope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java) // this will crash
```

Refer to the below for the discussion and finding
https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/786